# Why .append doesn't reload swiftUI view

Tags: swiftui

I have the following view hierarchy

```
Nurse List View > Nurse Card > Favorite button
```

Nurse List View

```
struct NurseListView: View {
    @State var data: [Nurse] = []

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                NurseCard(data: self.$data[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nurse Card

```
struct NurseCard: View {
    @Binding var data: Nurse
        
    var body: some View {
        FavoriteActionView(data:
            Binding(
                get: { self.data },
                set: { self.data = $0 as! Nurse }
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Favorite Action View

```
struct FavoriteActionView: View {
    @Binding var data: FavoritableData
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.toggleFavIcon()
        }) {
            VStack {
                Image(data.isFavorite ? "fav-icon" : "not-fav-icon")                    
                Text(String(data.likes.count))
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func toggleFavIcon() {
        if data.isFavorite {
            if let index = data.likes.firstIndex(of: AppState.currentUser.uid) {
                data.likes.remove(at: index)
            }
        } else {
            data.likes.append(AppState.currentUser.uid)
        }
    }
}
```

When `toggleFavIcon` execute, it append/remove the user id from the `likes` property in data object but I can't see the change unless I go back to previous page and reopen the page. What I am missing here?

Comment: Binding works unreliable on deep view hierarchy (ok, more that two), because for update only root is responsible. In case like your it is better to use ObservableObject view model as observed in every dependent view, then all will be updated as expected.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for your replay. I will try to read more about your approach and see how I can update my views.

Answer (score 0):

As Asperi wrote, using an ObservableObject would work well here.  Something like this:

```
class FavoritableData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var likes: [String] = []
    @Published var isFavorite = false
}

struct FavoriteActionView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: FavoritableData
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.toggleFavIcon()
        }) {
            VStack {
                Image(data.isFavorite ? "fav-icon" : "not-fav-icon")
                Text(String(data.likes.count))
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func toggleFavIcon() {
        if data.isFavorite {
            if let index = data.likes.firstIndex(of: AppState.currentUser.uid) {
                data.likes.remove(at: index)
            }
        } else {
            data.likes.append(AppState.currentUser.uid)
        }
    }
}
```